# How to stop unformatted json array being echoed

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, json

I have a bookmarks page where images are displayed. The images are being displayed fine however above the images, the array which the images are retrieved from is also displayed such as:

[["1",  "img/exampleImage1.png"], ["2",  "img/exampleImage2.png"]]

#### How can I avoid showing this text array but still keep my images?

This is the bookmarks page

```
  <?php include 'retrieveSymbol.php';?>

          <div id="bookmarkedSymbols"></div>

<script>
//populates product container

$.getJSON("retrieveSymbol.php", function(data){  //retrieves json array
  $.each(data, function(i, field){          //loops through array
    $("#bookmarkedSymbols").append(
             //creates product box filling it with data

       "<img src='" + field[1] + "'" + "id='symbol' alt='stadium'></a>"


    );
  });
});
</script>
```

This is the retrieve symbol page :

```
<?php
//connect to the database
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi ('localhost','root','','bookmarkedSymbols');
//query database
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM symbols");
//count the rows

if($resultSet->num_rows != 0) {
  //turn the results into an array
  $rows = $resultSet->fetch_all();
  echo json_encode($rows);

}else{
  echo "{no connection}";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question?

Comment: did you meant keep response from `retrieveSymbol.php` and use it later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the page with the JS, you don't need to include `retrieveSymbol.php` since you are calling it with AJAX.

Remove this:

```
<?php include 'retrieveSymbol.php';?>
```

When you include the php script it is echoing the JSON directly on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid including PHP Script explicitly again in the same PHP File. because this will get triggered through JavaScript asynchronously !

Try like below.

```
<div id="bookmarkedSymbols"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //populates product container
    $.getJSON("retrieveSymbol.php", function(data){  //retrieves json array
      $.each(data, function(i, field){          //loops through array
        $("#bookmarkedSymbols").append(
                 //creates product box filling it with data

           "<img src='" + field[1] + "'" + "id='symbol' alt='stadium'></a>"


        );
      });
    });
</script>
```

You can add document.ready function for this code like below.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

OR like below.

```
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Your `retrieveSymbol.php` code else case has invalid json and add `JSON Content Header`, correct like below.

```
<?php
//connect to the database
$mysqli = NEW MySQLi ('localhost','root','','bookmarkedSymbols');
//query database
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM symbols");
//count the rows

header('Content-Type: application/json');
if($resultSet->num_rows != 0) {
  //turn the results into an array
  $rows = $resultSet->fetch_all();

  echo json_encode($rows);

}else{
  echo '{"msg": "no connection"}';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I appreciate it! I have now corrected these errors.